# Placing a <table> within a <dd> of a <dl> adversely affects other elements of my page

Tags: html, html-table, html-lists

I am using a two-column layout with header and sticky footer only on right side.  The content area of my right column has a section and an aside displayed inline.

I am attempting to create a FAQ page.  I am using a description list for the questions and answers, and have a link at the bottom of the list to go back to the top.

For one of the answers (description data), I want to add a table of information.  I tried putting the table in place of the "dd", and then tried putting it within the "dd".  Either way, the table appears below the "Go to Top" link AND causes my footer to rise on the page and overlay the other information.

Is there a way to have the table be part of the "dd" without these adverse affects?  If not, what other viable solutions are there to format this page?

Here is the code for the affected areas of the page:

## FAQ

```
    <dl>
    <dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
    <dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
    <br>
    <dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
    <dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
    <br>
    <dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
    <dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
    <br>
    <dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
    <dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
    <br>
    <dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
    <dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question. Table below is                further explanation of answer.</dd>
    <dd>
    <table style="width: 600px; border:none;">
    <tr><th><a style="font-weight:bold;"><em>Header 1:</em></a></th></tr>
    <tr><th><a style="font-variant:small-caps; letter-spacing: 1px;"><em> Header 2 </em></a></th><td>- information$300 for up to 3 hours of play</td>        </tr>
     <tr><th><a style="font-variant:small-caps; letter-spacing: 1px;"><em> Header 3 </em></a></th><td>- information</td></tr>         
     <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
     <tr><th>  </th><td>- nformation</td></tr>
     <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
     <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
     <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
     <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
     <tr><th><a style="font-variant:small-caps; letter-spacing: 1px:"><em> Header 4 </em></a></th><td>- information</td></tr>
     </dd>
     <br>
    </dl>
    <a href="#top">Go to top</a>
    </section>

    <aside><h2>Comments</h2>
    <div class="blockquote"><blockquote><q> love You Two!</q></blockquote>        </div>
    <p class="name">person</p>
    <div class="blockquote"><blockquote><q>I love You Two!</q></blockquote></div>
    <p class="name">person</p>
    <div class="blockquote"><blockquote><q>I love You Two!</q></blockquote></div>
    <p class="name">person</p></aside>
    <div id="footer">
    <div>&copy;Copyright 2015. All Rights Reserved.</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the opened `<table>` tag. Close it using `</table>` before the `</dd>`. 
The code will be

```
<dl>
<dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
<dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
<br>
<dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
<dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
<br>
<dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
<dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
<br>
<dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
<dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question.</dd>
<br>
<dt>Q &nbsp Question?</dt>
<dd>A &nbsp Paragraph of information to answer question. Table below is                further explanation of answer.</dd>
<dd>
<table style="width: 600px; border:none;">
<tr><th><a style="font-weight:bold;"><em>Header 1:</em></a></th></tr>
<tr><th><a style="font-variant:small-caps; letter-spacing: 1px;"><em> Header 2 </em></a></th><td>- information$300 for up to 3 hours of play</td>        </tr>
 <tr><th><a style="font-variant:small-caps; letter-spacing: 1px;"><em> Header 3 </em></a></th><td>- information</td></tr>         
 <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
 <tr><th>  </th><td>- nformation</td></tr>
 <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
 <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
 <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
 <tr><th>  </th><td>- information</td></tr>
 <tr><th><a style="font-variant:small-caps; letter-spacing: 1px:"><em> Header 4 </em></a></th><td>- information</td></tr>
 </table> <!-- You missed  out this tag -->
 </dd>
 <br>
</dl>
<a href="#top">Go to top</a>
</section>

<aside><h2>Comments</h2>
<div class="blockquote"><blockquote><q> love You Two!</q></blockquote>        </div>
<p class="name">person</p>
<div class="blockquote"><blockquote><q>I love You Two!</q></blockquote></div>
<p class="name">person</p>
<div class="blockquote"><blockquote><q>I love You Two!</q></blockquote></div>
<p class="name">person</p></aside>
<div id="footer">
<div>&copy;Copyright 2015. All Rights Reserved.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it! Just needed another set of eyes. I appreciate the help, geo.